# What is meaning of dialogue at the end of Masaan about going to Sangam twice?

Tags: dialogue, masaan

In the ending scene of the Bollywood film [Masaan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4635372/) aka Fly Away Solo two characters, a boy and girl, take a ride to the river coast at another side of Ganga in a boat. The boy says that

> वैसे [संगम](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triveni_Sangam) दो बार आना चाहिए, एक बार अकेले, और एक बार किसी और के साथ
>
> Translation: One should come twice to the [Sangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triveni_Sangam), once alone and once with someone else.

What's the significance of that dialogue?

Comment: Without context I'm only guessing, but it sounds like thr principle is that you come on your own to soak in the experience without distraction, then again with someone so that you have someone to share that experience with.

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be because Sangam means "Milan" or "coming together". But I am not able to completely understand either. It intrigued me which is why I googled it and came across your post. The rivers come alone there and then meet and become one which is probably why they say you should come there alone and then again with someone to show the "Sangam" your own "Sangam" perhaps!

Answer (score 0):

One comes to the sangam alone at death and with partner when alive.

In masaan, a place where people come after death, alone.

Hope... where they show them going together to Sangam and his saying the last line is symbolic of new beginnings and hope.